# Converting 3D coordinate to screen coordinate in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am facing a problem with converting 3D coordinate to screen coordinate. I have to convert the center of sphere to the screen coordinate. My code is here:

```
//  OpenGL problem

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

void passive(int,int);
void reshape(int,int);
void init(void);
void display(void);
void camera(void);

int cursorX,cursorY,width,height;
double centerX,centerY,centerZ;
//GLfloat modelviewMatrix[16],projectionMatrix[16];
GLdouble modelviewMatrix[16],projectionMatrix[16];
GLint viewport[4];

int main (int argc,char **argv) {
    glutInit (&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1364,689);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Sample");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(passive);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display() {
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //  Render 3D content
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,1.0,100.0);    // create 3D perspective projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    camera();
    glTranslatef(-6,-2,0);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glutSolidSphere(5,50,50);
    glPopMatrix();

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewMatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionMatrix);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    // get 3D coordinates based on window coordinates  
    gluProject(-6, -2, 0, modelviewMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewport, &centerX, &centerY, &centerZ);

    // Render 2D content
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, width,height, 0);                 // create 2D orthographic projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f( centerX,centerY );          // coordinate of center of the sphere in orthographic projection
        glVertex2f( cursorX,cursorY );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void camera(void) {
    glRotatef(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslated(0,0,-20);
}

void init(void) {
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    width=w; height=h;
}

void passive(int x1,int y1) {
    cursorX=x1; cursorY=y1;
}
```

In my code the centerX and centerY coordinates are going out of the screen. I have to draw a line between the center of the sphere and the mouse pointer. Any modification to the code to get it working properly?

Comment: How is this any different from [the question you asked last month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926763/mapping-coordinates-from-3d-perspective-projection-to-2d-orthographic-projection)

Comment: Had got only one answer to that thread. Tried it out but couldn't get it working. The code has been modified to include what was suggested in that thread. Still getting weird results.

Comment: You don't keep asking the same question just because you didn't get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the function I use to switch between 3D / 2D coordinate. See if it works for you.

```
void toggle2DMode(bool flag, GLint Width, GLint Height) const
{
        if(flag)
        {
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glPushMatrix();
                glLoadIdentity();

                glOrtho(0.0, Width, Height, 0.0, -1.0f, 1.0f);
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glPushMatrix();
                glLoadIdentity();
                glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        }
        else
        {
                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glPopMatrix();
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                glPopMatrix();
                glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        }
}
```

Comment: Let me re-frame my question. If there is a point x,y,z in 3D coordinate system, then what is its corresponding x,y on the screen coordinate system?

Comment: Oh. Did you try simply using [gluProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml) function? Function definition: Map object coordinates to window coordinates

Comment: I have used gluProject in the code I have written above. It gives weird results. The x,y,z values that the gluProject returned were out of the screen. I wanted both the mouse position (2D) and the center of sphere(3D) to be in the same coordinate system. I was unable to convert 3D to 2D.  
But now I managed to convert 2D mouse coordinate to 3D coordinate system. This solved my problem. Picked the code from NeHe tutorials.  
My updated code : (coverting 2D to 3D using gluUnProject) :  
[link](http://pastebin.com/PSSkkJJV)

Answer (score 0):

my function for checking resolution of a quad

```
void WINDOW_TEXT::calcResolution( GLshort & x , GLshort & y )
{
    GLdouble tx, ty, ttx, tty, z; // target 2d coords (z is 'unused')

    GLdouble model_view[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model_view);

    GLdouble projection[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    // get window coords based on 3D coordinates
    gluProject( up_right.x, up_right.y, up_right.z,
                model_view, projection, viewport,
                &tx, &ty, &z);

    gluProject( down_left.x, down_left.y, down_left.z,
                model_view, projection, viewport,
                &ttx, &tty, &z);

    x = (GLshort)(tx-ttx);
    y = (GLshort)(tty-ty);
};
```

"z" is ignored and you get pure resolution stored in x, and y